# How do I store input message in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to save my input field message in vuex store state. I am having issues with this. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="app_right-bot">
        <form @v-on:submit.prevent="storeMessage">
          <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" v-model="message">
</form>

      </div>
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
   storeMessage() {
      this.$store.dispatch('storeMessage', this.message )
    }
  }
```

Then in my vuex I have

```
 export const ADD_MSG = "ADD_MSG"


export default createStore({
  state: {
    message: []
  },
  mutations: {
    [ADD_MSG](state, message) {
      state.message = message
    }
  },
  actions: {
    storeMessage({commit}, message) {
      commit(ADD_MSG, message);
        }
  },
```

In another component I am trying to display the message but I am getting error:
Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

```
 <div class="app_right-message" v-for="msg in message" :key="msg.id">
            <p>{{message}}</p>

 computed: {
         ...mapState({
             message: state => state.message
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first time your `mapState` function is called, `state.obj` is undefined (as storeMessage wasn't called yet), hence the error message. You might want to check that in your mapper:

```
state => state.obj && state.obj.message
```

Additionally, it's not really clear why do you need that 'obj' property in first place.

---

As a matter of fact, when you fix that one, you'll receive the same error on this line:

```
state.obj.message = message
```

... as there's no autovivification in JS, and `obj` property is not on your store object; you need to create it (or, as said above, just ditch it and go along with storing the messages directly on state).

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.
i changed it to `message: state => state.message` and added to state `messages : []`

Comment: So it's stored on state as `message` - or `messages`?

Comment: typo, as message

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Do you receive an error, or there's just no propagations: the message created in one component is not received in another one?

Comment: i've sorted this out. I had @v-on instead of v-on.

Comment: ... so `storeMessage` has never been called

Comment: yes but i've still got a problem, for some reason it adds 4 records instead of 1, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Why do you use `v-for="msg in message"` if message is supposed to be a single one?

Comment: Because messages are in a mapState `message: state => state.message` How else can I display it?

Comment: You have a single message, not an array. What's `v-for` for?